# Mocking a select with mapping in Go is returning expected transaction begin error

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-sqlmock

I'm trying to do a simple unit test using go-sqlmock to do a select and return a mapped ID. Code snippet below

```golang
    s.sqlmock.ExpectBegin()
    s.sqlmock.
        ExpectQuery("select `id` from `project` where `id` = \\? and `archived` = \\1").
        WithArgs(2).
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id"}).AddRow(strconv.Itoa(1)))
    s.sqlmock.ExpectCommit()
```

The snippet of the implementation I want to test on is:

```golang
...

    type Project struct{ Id int64 }

    var project Project

    tx.Raw("select id from project where id = ? and archived = 1", values["projectId"]).Scan(&project)

...
```

But the following error occurs:

[image]

I've tried some examples but without success. I thank the help of all you

**UPDATE**

---

I tried to remove `s.sqlmock.ExpectBegin() and s.sqlmock.ExpectCommit()` of code and change a query as below:

```
    s.sqlmock.
        ExpectQuery("select id from project where id = ? and archived = 1").
        WithArgs(2).
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id"}).AddRow(strconv.Itoa(1)))
```

But the following error occurs:

> Query: could not match actual sql: "select id from project where id =
> ? and archived = 1" with expected regexp "select id from project where
> id = ? and archived = 1"

Comment: maybe you need to set the query matcher. https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#customize-sql-query-matching

Comment: WoW @mh-cbon works fine!!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, the user response @mh-cbon worked perfectly. I replaced my default matcher for full case sensitive and the test passed!

before:

```
    var sqlDB *sql.DB

    sqlDB, s.sqlmock, _ = sqlmock.New()
    s.db, _ = gorm.Open("mysql", sqlDB)
```

after:

```
    var sqlDB *sql.DB

    sqlDB, s.sqlmock, _ = sqlmock.New(sqlmock.QueryMatcherOption(sqlmock.QueryMatcherEqual))
    s.db, _ = gorm.Open("mysql", sqlDB)
```